# Why do standard associative ordered containers allow `const char*` as their key?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, stdset

As far as I know we should never compare two const character strings using relational operators `<>`... because the fact that it compares the addresses rather than the values:

```
const char* sz1 = "Hello";
const char* sz2 = "hello";
if(sz1 < sz2);// not valid. So use strcmp instead.
```

- What I've noticed that Ordered Associative Containers like `map, multimap, set, multiset` impose a restriction on their `key` so that the key should some how be compared to order the elements in the container. The default operator for the key is `<` operator.

Everything is clear until I've created a `map, set` of `const char*` then I get the results incorrect:

```
std::set<const char*> scp{ "Hello", "World", "C++", "Programming" };    
std::set<std::string> sstr{ "Hello", "World", "C++", "Programming" };

// error
std::copy(scp.cbegin(), scp.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;

// Ok 
std::copy(sstr.cbegin(), sstr.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

- It is apparent that `scp` compares pointers to character strings while `sstr` is Ok as long as class `string` has defined `<` to work properly.
- Why STL allows this? (creating associative containers whose key element type is a `char*`) and why here's even no warning?

Comment: Counter-argument: why bog down standard containers with provision against what *might* be a pointer to a C-style string, since you're not supposed to use C-style strings in C++ anyway?

Comment: Just because it won't work for this simple case doesn't mean someone else won't have a use-case where pointers as keys might not be useful. Besides, your case can be solved by providing your own comparison function that uses `strcmp`.

Comment: I even think that `sz1 < sz2` is UB (whereas `std::less<>{}(sz1, sz2)` is not).

Comment: @Jarod42 unless they point into the same array, yes.

Comment: You might want to compare only pointers. Why forbid that (even if unusual)? And for warning, what would be the correct way to express the intent to compare pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The default operator for the key is `<` operator.

This is not true.  The default comparison operator for the non-hashed associative containers is [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).  `std::less` uses `operator <` for comparisons, but with one key difference.  Unlike the pointers built in `operator <` where

> neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other.

<sup>[source](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.rel#4.3.sentence-1)</sup>

`std::less` has that the

> specializations for any pointer type yield a strict total order that is consistent among those specializations and is also consistent with the partial order imposed by the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`.

<sup>[source](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/comparisons#2.sentence-1)</sup>

So this is a safe operation and we can reliably store pointers in the map.

Comment: But in C++ primer 5 ed by Lipman: "The associative containers place constraints on the type that is used as a key. We’ll
cover the requirements for keys in the unordered containers in § 11.4 (p. 445). For
the ordered containers—map, multimap, set, and multiset—the key type must
define a way to compare the elements. By default, the library uses the < operator for
the key type to compare the keys." "Requirements on Key Type".

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa He over simplified/was mistaken.  By default it uses `std::less` which uses `operator <` but with some more guarantees when it comes to pointers.  You can see [in the C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) that `std::set` uses `std::less` for `Compare`

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, maybe sometimes you *want* pointer comparisons, and if you don't then the container allows you to supply your own custom comparison operator like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct CStrCmp {
    bool operator() (const char* lhs, const char* rhs) const {
        return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::set<const char*, CStrCmp> scp{ "Hello", "World", "C++", "Programming" };
    std::set<std::string> sstr{ "Hello", "World", "C++", "Programming" };

    // This works too now
    std::copy(scp.cbegin(), scp.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<const char*>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Ok 
    std::copy(sstr.cbegin(), sstr.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```